# How do I set the default document of an Azure App Service when it exists in a subdirectory?

Tags: laravel, azure, iis, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am deploying an Azure App Service from Azure DevOps via a release pipeline that is configured to perform an Azure App Service Deploy task on my build agent. The deploy task targets the root of my App Service, so it will be deployed in my '\site\wwwroot\' folder.

[image: Azure DevOps release pipeline configuration]

My project is a Laravel PHP web application, so the default document is set to 'index.php'. My application is deployed to '\site\wwwroot\', but the location of my 'index.php' file that is set to the default document however is in '\site\wwwroot\'.

[image: Azure App Service Application Settings for default document and virtual application directories]

Not a big problem, right? Just set the application directory to '\site\wwwroot\public' and the app works because it can now find my default document (index.php). Except there's one problem.

When Azure DevOps deploys to an Azure App Service, it is going to deploy to the application directory that you set in Azure. Because my root is set to '\site\wwwroot\public' now to correct the issue with finding the default document, AzureDevops is deploying subsequent builds to the '\site\wwwroot\public' folder.

Ideally, I would like to keep my 'index.php' file within my '\site\wwwroot\public' folder, as it causes issues when I move it to the root of my project. I can't seem to figure out how to tell Azure to look in my public folder for the default document. Do I need to write a web.config and place it in my project root for IIS to find it?

---

Update:

I'm still attempting to resolve this issue I am having. I am not able to configure Azure or Azure DevOps to differentiate between the directory that my app is deployed to, and the directory that my application is served from.

I cannot simply create two virtual applications, as that would expose my root directory to that endpoint. I need to be able to simply instruct Azure DevOps where to place my application on the Web App.

Comment: To anyone who knows how I can move my index.php file to the root of my Laravel project, I am willing to do this as well. I edited my index.php to load from __DIR__.'/bootstrap', however I now get a 404 on all of my public resources (app.css, app.js).

Comment: Rename server.php in your Laravel root folder to index.php

Comment: @JigneshJoisar Now my app.css and app.js are coming back empty. No 404 now, just empty resources.

Comment: We are having the exact same issues. Did you find a solution for it at all?

Comment: I'm currently waiting for an Azure support technician to get back to me. I added an answer to this question, but it doesn't appear to be exactly what I was looking for. I found somewhere in the Azure App Service docs that stated having your index.php in the root is a requirement.

Comment: Remember, you could always use Docker to get it configured exactly how you want it, but using the Azure App Service would be much more convenient. Looks like deploying 'Any language on any platform' isn't all it's cracked up to be.

Answer (score 0):

- Renaming the server.php to index.php
- Copy the .htaccess from public folder to root folder
- Changing .htaccess :

  ```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/
  RewriteRule ^(css|js|images)/(.*)$ public/$1/$2 [L,NC]
  ```

> change to function /Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php/asset() function
>   as follows:

```
function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
    return app('url')->asset("public/".$path, $secure);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, no luck. My css and js are not able to be found. The app loads the HTML from my blade template fine, but it can't find '/css' or '/js' folders. It also looks like server.php is only for development purposes, so I'd rather find a way to fix the issue using conventional methods.

Comment: @ColinLaws just try last one method

Comment: I can't modify the Laravel framework directly, that would cause maintainability issues. This is for production, not a hack to get by temporarily for development If I changed that file, how would those changes be reflected in my repository? They couldn't. It's a composer dependency.

Comment: I agree, this is best solved on Azure's end, but I can't differentiate between the app's root folder and the folder containing my default document.

Comment: for the security reason and separation of  public asset files laravel use public folder

Comment: I understand, that's why I asked the question. The question is about Azure, not Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Since it works fine after setting application directory to '\site\wwwroot\public', so you can add a new virtual application with 'site\wwwroot\public' physical path instead of change the original one.

Then, there are two items, for example:

[image]

Regarding deploy through Azure DevOps, just deploy app to that app service (site\wwwroot).

After that, you can access you app through [app service url]\PHP.

Comment: This does not work, as exposing the physical path of 'site\wwwroot' to the virtual path of '/' will expose all of my files in the project root. This also does not work, as my application is not configured to route with a virtual path of /PHP or anything else for that matter.

Answer (score 0):

You are capable of specifying the location where source code is deployed to from Azure DevOps (or Git, BitBucket, etc.) by providing your Azure App Service with a Kudu environment variable. Please see the following environment variables configured in the 'Application Settings' section of the Azure Portal for my Azure App Service.

[image: Environment variable configured for the source code management path (SCM_REPOSITORY_PATH and SCM_TARGET_PATH Kudu variables)]

This allows me to instruct where the code is deployed. Otherwise, it appears that Kudu's default source code management path is taken from your Virtual application paths.

Further reading:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-inplace-and-without-repository

---

Update:

It appears that while you are capable of configuring the location that your code is deployed using the Kudu environment variables, you are still limited to the folder name of your Virtual Application.

For instance, if I set the SCM_TARGET_PATH to `\home\sites\app`, and I have a virtual application with a virtual path of `/` and a physical path of `\home\sites\app\public`, Azure DevOps will deploy your code into `\home\sites\app\public` and not the expected `\home\sites\app`.

This is a huge inconvenience, I cannot host my Laravel application because my continuous deployment will not work the way Azure currently works. I would have to publish my code to a Docker container and use that instead (which I don't want to do).

Comment: any progress in a true solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The team at Microsoft just expects you to change your project to be hosted out of the root folder. You cannot host from a file within a subdirectory of your wwwroot.