# Azure Devops Webapp Deployment wwwroot instead of wwwroot\public

Tags: azure-devops, azure-deployment, azure-webapps

When deploying to Azure Webapp Windows through Azure Devops.

So the issue is this. I know making the Physical Path to 'site\wwwroot' and virtual path of '/' will deploy my code to my wwwroot folder however I need the path to go to 'wwwroot\public' so that my application will work. This is a Laravel Application

How can I set this so that when I do a Deployment it adds my code to wwwroot instead of wwwroot\public but still keep access to my application.

Comment: You can refer to these cases: [case1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52337455/how-do-i-set-the-default-document-of-an-azure-app-service-when-it-exists-in-a-su) [case2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55250240/deploying-into-azure-web-app-web-root-with-azure-devops-task-azure-app-service).

Comment: Try to create a web.config on the public folder and then add this line:
`<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" appendQueryString="true"/>` If the configuration is all done,  try to restart the app and see if that helps.